# multiline matching with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I was constructing a regular expression with one multiline matching:
https://regex101.com/r/Ezgeev/1

Yet, it seems I can't transfer this to perl:

```
s/^\s*"concept_rule":\s*"(.|\n)*?[^\\]".*//mg
```

At least, this will not match over multiple lines (single line matches work).
Is this due to differences in the regex syntax or some flag problem?

Comment: Try adding the `s` modifier to your regex, see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) for details on the regexp modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

It matches for me.

```
say "<<$_>>" for $string
    =~ /^(\s*"concept_rule":\s*"(?:.|\n)*?[^\\]".*)/mg;
```

I changed the inner `()` to `(?:)` because you probably don't want to capture the newlines or last characters.